# How to scale xvfb?

Tags: image-manipulation, xvfb

I'm looking to develop a web-application that translates request parameters into a PNG/GIF chart. I'm looking to reuse an open source charting library, but I have concerns about the scalability.

A long time ago, we were using a single Xvfb buffer to render our image into, but that basically meant servicing only one incoming request at a time.

According to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xvfb) it seems we can create numerous buffers? If so, is it simply ensuring there is enough physical RAM to prevent excessive paging?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xvfb-run your-command`. It takes care of set up and clean up.

From the man page:

> xvfb-run is a wrapper for the Xvfb(1x)
>   command which simplifies the task of
>   running commands (typically an X
>   client, or a script containing a list
>   of clients to be run) within a virtual
>   X server environment. xvfb-run sets up
>   an X authority file, writes a cookie
>   to it (see xauth(1x)) and then starts
>   the Xvfb X server as a background
>   process. The process ID of Xvfb is
>   stored for later use. The specified
>   command is then run using the X
>   display corresponding to the Xvfb
>   server just started and the X
>   authority file created earlier.
>
> When the command exits, its status is
>   saved, the Xvfb server is killed
>   (using the process ID stored earlier),
>   the X authority cookie removed, and
>   the authority file deleted. xvfb-run
>   then exits with the exit status of
>   command.